# Devexpress XRtableCell thousand separator?

Tags: string, devexpress, separator, xtrareport, tablecell

How can I add thousand separator for specifices number cells in XRTable? I don't need the currency unit or the decimal dot like this:

```
 xrTableCell35.DataBindings["Text"].FormatString = "{0:C}";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`«The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier»`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx):

```cs
xrTableCell35.DataBindings["Text"].FormatString = "{0:N0}";
```

Or you can use [`«The "," Custom Specifier»`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx):

```cs
xrTableCell35.DataBindings["Text"].FormatString = "{0:#,#}";
```